# iOS - How to add UISearchController.searchBar to a controller without a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I've looked for tutorials of `UISearchController` and all of them are implemented this way:

```
├── MainTableViewController(UITableViewController*)
   ├── SearchController(UISearchController*)
   └── ResultTableViewController(UITableViewController*)
```

In this way, the `SearchController.searchBar` can be displayed at the top of the view simply by

`MainTableViewController.tableView.tableHeaderView = SearchController.searchBar;`

How can I add the `searchBar` to the top of a controller **which is not a `UITableViewController`**?

Comment: Add UISearchbar as tableview header .Don't mix UISearchbar with UISearchController.

Comment: You can add UISearchbar and uitableview in UIViewController .

Comment: Did you find a way to implement `UISearchController` without a table view?

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard select your viewController and open Utilities(top right icon) and search for `UISearchBar`. Now drag the `UISearchBar` into your viewController and set frame/constraints. And make a coonection for added searchbar to your viewController class.

In side your viewController class set delegate for search bar

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
  super.viewDidLoad()
  searchBar.delegate = self          
}
```

Now implement `searchBar:textDidChange` method

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
{

}
```

Comment: Yes I know there's `UISearchBar` I can use. But what confused me is actually the fact that `UISearchController` already has a property `searchBar`. If I create a `UISearchBar`, then there will be two `UISearchBar`. What I want is to pop up the result table view when the user is typing. How to do that?

Comment: no need to use UISearchController here, simply use UISearchBar and by using  the delegate method filter the results and present a tableViewController by passing these filtered results

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine without a table view. The UISearchDisplayController instance needs a searchResultsDatasource and delegate, which are really UITableView datasource and delegate.

Since these implementations are present in UITableViews, they are often reused as the implementations for the search controller, but that needn't be the case.

Comment: But Apple recommend using `UISearchController` and `UISearchDisplayController` is deprecated in iOS8.